# Remove beamer markup

Tags: beamer, tools, html

I have a `main.book.tex` and a `main.beamer.tex` which then `\input` the same source files. In those source files, I have a lot of `\mode<>` designations and generally, a lot of beamer markup -`\overlayarea`'s, `\only<>`'s, etc.  My problem is that I also want to output to HTML. Now, `tex4ht` is generally awesome, generally plays nice with `beamer` and `beamerarticle`, and I've spend a lot of time customizing it to get it to do what I want. But, I'd like to try other conversion tools (e.g. pandoc) that can't handle `beamer` markup. Are there any good tools I could run my files through to remove the beamer markup? I've started writing a script to do this, but I thought maybe tex.sx already knows of such tools or has better ideas.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so.

The best bet -- and probably fastest approach -- is to write some regular expression scripts that remove exactly what you want.

Candidates are `sed` (http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), `Perl` (perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html , perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), and `Python` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

You can have these scripts run automatically if you incorporate calling them into an automated build system like `make` or `SCons`.